# linked list syntax in C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to understand the syntax of linked lists by visualising it through diagrams. However I am getting confused. This code prints out 0-9. I don't understand the commented bits, please explain visually.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int item;
    struct node* link;
};

int main()
{
    struct node *start,*list;
    int i;
    start = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //???????
    list = start; // ????????
    start->link = NULL; // ??????????
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        list->item = i;
        list->link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        list = list->link;
    }
    list->link = NULL; //????????????
    while(start != NULL) //??????????????
    {
        printf("%d\n",start->item);
        start = start->link;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read an algorithms and data structures book or just search the web. There are plenty of resources that explain linked lists, including visually.

Comment: I understand linked lists, and have read many resources on it, however each link seems to be using different syntax to explain, so whats left is me feeling even more confused wen I started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    struct node *start,*list;
    int i;
    // Allocate memory for a single node
    start = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); //???????
    // The head of the list is starting node.
    // (This head represented by `list` will be advanced when building;
    //  while the head represented by `start` will not be advanced
    //  until iterating for display.)
    list = start; // ????????
    // The starting node has no 'next' yet.
    // (This is not technically needed in this exact code.
    //  The code would have been more clear with the assignment of
    //  null to the 'next' after each malloc to start with a clean node.)
    start->link = NULL; // ??????????
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        list->item = i;
        list->link = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        list = list->link; // Move to the next (newly created) node.
    }
    // The last node has no 'next' node. Need to manually assign it
    // a value because it "could be anything" until properly initialized.
    // (Intermediate nodes have had the 'next' assigned in the loop.)
    list->link = NULL; //????????????

    // Iterate over the list, using `start` to track the head and
    // keep iterating until the end of the list is reached.
    while(start != NULL) //??????????????
    {
        printf("%d\n",start->item);
        start = start->link; // Move to the 'next' node
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Compare it with the following which, hopefully, makes the goal/intent more clear:

```
struct node *create_node(int value) {
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    n->item = value; // all nodes start with some value
    n->link = NULL;  // all nodes start without a 'next'
    return n;
}

int main()
{
    struct node *start,*list;
    int i;

    // Create list of elements 0..9
    // (Creating the start node first avoids a condition check;
    //  pulling out the value assignment from the subsequent/trailing loop
    //  is for clarity.)
    start = create_node(0);
    list = start;
    for(i = 1; i < 10; i++) // Changed loop count - value assigned in create
    {
        list->link = create_node(i);
        list = list->link;
    }

    // Display - note reset of tracked head to beginning of list
    list = start;
    while(list != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d\n", list->item);
        list = list->link;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the new code, it is definitely clear. 

However I am having trouble understanding the references. For example Struct node *start is a variable start that points to a struct node. Likewise with Struct node *list.

But what does list = start mean? Does it mean you take start which is a pointer to a struct and equate it to list which was a pointer to its own struct but now pointing to start instead?

Comment: @Hyune `x = y` is always an assignment. In this case it assigns the value of the *pointer*, Meaning, that after `list = start`, both *pointers* refer to the same object/struct (the one just allocated in the first case). Pointer variables  (eg. `struct node *`) must be assigned meaningful values before they are used. It is the `malloc` that actually allocates the node objects in memory (and such objects are accessed via the returned pointers).

Comment: Thank you so much! I get it now ^^